# Business Catalyst Responsive Catalog Tables

Tags: css, responsive-design, business-catalyst

So the unfortunate thing about BC is that it uses tables to contain it's product/catalog grids.

I have my catalog page set to display 4 columns of items. The problem with this is it remains 4 on a mobile device. I tried to add a clear to the catalogueItem and it's having none of it.

Does anyone know how I can make it only display 1 column when using a mobile device?

The page in question is [here](http://radshaperc.businesscatalyst.com/rc-models).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off tables for your products/catalog grids.

This is the code that is found in the `Layouts > OnlineShop > page_contact.html`

This is an example:

```
{tag_productlist, perRow, target, perPage, sort, hideEmptyMessage, listType}
```

set the last option, `listType`, to `true` and it renders as an unordered list, then it is simple to do with whatever grid system you are using.

Example:  `{tag_productlist,3,,50,,true,true}`